# Why should we use the "write" methods in filechannel while they already exist in RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, nio

This is my code, which uses `FileChannel` to write to the file:

```
package logging;

import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {  

            RandomAccessFile rf = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Users\\kalyan\\Desktop", "rw");
            FileChannel fc = rf.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            byteBuffer.putChar('a');

            while(byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                fc.write(byteBuffer); //usig filechannel to write to the file
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, I am using `FileChannel`'s `write` method to write to the file, i.e., `fc.write`.

Why shouldn't we use `rf.write`, which already exists in `RandomAccessFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no reason not to use the `write()` methods which exist on `RandomAccessFile`.  if you happen to be interacting with code which requires a `WritableByteChannel`, however, you would want to use the `FileChannel` instead of `RandomAccessFile.`

Answer (score 1):

In your example it makes no difference, but if you used ByteBuffer.allocateDirect you could write faster. ByteBuffer API says

*A byte buffer is either direct or non-direct. Given a direct byte buffer, the Java virtual machine will make a best effort to perform native I/O operations directly upon it. That is, it will attempt to avoid copying the buffer's content to (or from) an intermediate buffer before (or after) each invocation of one of the underlying operating system's native I/O operations*

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is no `RandomAccessFile.write` overload that takes a byte buffer I'd say the reason for using the file channel is pretty obvious. But lets assume you really meant your question in a more general manner. Being able to manipulate a RAF via its file channel opens up a variety of additional functionality:

- File region locking
- Memory mapping
- Byte swaps from other channel objects
- Writing to portions of the file without modifying the current file pointer

It is this added functionality you will be looking at if you use a RAF's file channel, as opposed to the simple ability to write data at the current FP.